# Python/Pandas: Drop duplicate rows in dataframe, concatenate values in one column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column (A) with duplicate values. But the other column (B) has unique values for each value in (A).

```
     A   B
0  6SP  6A
1  6SP  6B
2  6FR  6A
```

I want to drop the duplicates in col (A) but still retain all values in col (B) by concatenation. The result should look like

```
     A      B
0  6SP  6A,6B
2  6FR     6A
```

Is this possible? The dataset is not very big (approx. 1000 rows) so efficiency is not very important.
Sample code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":['6SP','6SP','6FR'], "B":['6A','6B','6A']})
```

Best regards,
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(", ".join)
```

Comment: rather dupe close like answer ;)

Comment: Thanks for the push in the right direction.This did the trick:
`dg = df.groupby(['A'])['B'].apply(','.join).reset_index(name='B')`

Comment: @jezrael what? (sorry, my english is not the best)

Comment: @david891 the `name = 'B'` part is not necessary, you can let the parentheses empty